# Laravel 5.5 Eloquent WhenLoaded relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

On the [Laravel 5.5 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources), under **Conditional Relationships**, it says

> whenLoaded method may be used to conditionally load a relationship

I tried in my code

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'roles' => Role::collection($this->whenLoaded('roles')),
        'remember_token' => $this->remember_token,
    ];
}
```

According to the documentation, the roles key is removed from the resource response entirely before it is sent to the client because the relationship hasn't been loaded.

How do I load a relationship? How do I determine if a relationship is loaded? In this case how do I load `Role` (model)?

Comment: As I understand it, the `roles` will be filled if you have loaded the relationship wither via `Model::with("roles")` or `$modelObject->load("roles")`

Comment: you can try to Create Role resource.

Answer (score 6):

**Eager Loading**

Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model.

```
$user = App\User::with('roles')->find($id);
```

**Lazy Eager Loading**

To eager load a relationship after the parent model has already been retrieved

```
$user->load('roles');
```

**Load Missing Relationships**

To load a relationship *only* when it has not already been loaded

```
$user->loadMissing('roles');
```