# Conditional relationship not appearing in Laravel Resource API

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use [Laravel's API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources) to handle some JSON and I'm not able to conditionally load a relationship, despite it being eager loaded.

My controller:

```
$games = Game::with('availableInterests')->get();
```

In my view, I'm json encoding the collection to be used in VueJS

```
games = @json(new \App\Http\Resources\GameCollection($games)),
```

**GameCollection** - unchanged from the class Laravel generated for me.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class GameCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

**GameResource**

```
class GameResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'thumbnail_url' => $this->thumbnail_url,
            'available_interests' => Interest::collection($this->whenLoaded('availableInterests')),
        ];
    }
}
```

Game Model's Relationship

```
public function availableInterests() : BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Interest::class);
}
```

I've tried changing `$this->whenLoaded('availableInterests')` to `$this->whenLoaded('available_interests')` with no luck.  I've double checked my spelling with no luck.

**Why isn't this [conditional relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships) present in the json?**

Even removing `$this->whenLoaded()` doesn't make this relationship appear.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421856/laravel-5-5-eloquent-whenloaded-relationship

Comment: @scipilot I don't think so, given I'm already using `with()` to eager load the relationship

Comment: Have you made a resource class for `Interest`? What works for me in my API app is `'reviews' => ReviewResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('reviews'))`.

Comment: Do you get an error? As @ashraj98 said, 'available_interests' needs to be a resource. Looks like you are using the eloquent model

Comment: try to force eager loading in your Model `$with = ['availableInterests'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need GameCollection in this case.

I would try doing this:

**InterestResource.php** (create new class)

```
class InterestResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
        // or what ever array structure you want
    }
}
```

**GameResource.php**

```
class GameResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'thumbnail_url' => $this->thumbnail_url,
            'available_interests' => InterestResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('availableInterests')),
        ];
    }
}
```

**Your Controller**

```
$games = Game::with('availableInterests')->get();
```

**Your View**

```
games = @json(\App\Http\Resources\GameResource::collection($games)),
```